# Sketching the graph of a fourth degree polynomial curve

Tags: graphing-functions

My approach doesn't seem to work.

$$(y^2-2)^2+(x^2-2)^2=2.$$

Any suggestions and solutions would be appreciated .

Comment: And what is your approach...?

Comment: But these things apply to a function. And what's more, to a function of one variable. You don't have an explicit function here, that is an equation with two variables. We might consider it an implicit function, but I think you need to state that (and try to extract an explicit function, if possible, or at least decide if it is $y$ as a function of $x$ or $x$ as a function of $y$).

Comment: Try to find a domain first. What values of $x$ and what values of $y$ *may*, and what values *can't* satisfy the equation?

Comment: YEh, I noticed that . I thought expanding brackets would be too tiresome . So.

Comment: If you forget the squares for $x, y$, you get a circle around $(2,2)$ with radius $\sqrt 2$. All those points have to be replaced by their square root, and can be positive or negative (so we have 3 mirror images). And otherwise, just wolfram it: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28y%5E2%E2%88%922%29%5E2%2B%28x%5E2%E2%88%922%29%5E2%3D2

Answer (score 3):

Writing $u=x^2$ and $v=y^2$ we get the equation
$$(v-2)^2+(u-2)^2 = 2,$$
so we know that $(x^2,y^2)$ must lie on the upper-right quarter of the circle of radius $\sqrt{2}$ centered in $(2,2)$. To get the graph (or a good approximation thereof), you can draw this quarter of circle, and then take the square root(s) of the coordinates of its points to get points of your graph.